# What is the Most Efficient Way to Query for "Similar" Numeric Values?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible use a MySQL query to perform this kind of check? If not, what's the most efficient method or algorithm for performing this check in a language like PHP?

I've been tasked with the following:

> When entering a new client, check the SSN entered by the user against the `clients` table to see if there are any other records that have an SSN similar<sup>1</sup> to the one entered.
>
> <sup>1</sup> *Similar is being defined as having a value where 5 of the numbers in the client's SSN in the database match the SSN being entered in both value and position.*

**Examples of Data That Could be Returned:**

Entered Value: 599151223 (From the form)

Matching Values: **5**33**1**4**122**8

The numbers in bold are numbers that match the entered SSN in both position and value.

Comment: I don't know if this can be efficiently implemented in sql. But, maybe, full-text search engines can help? Sphinx, for example.

Comment: It would obviously be a terrible way to store the data for other reasons but if you did a single digit per columns then you could use SQL to run this query easily.  I would say do the comparison in php.

Comment: I don't understand why this would ever need to be done. ESPECIALLY with SSN's.

Comment: it can be done in mysql but too long and slow query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can do it with SQL (maybe only with FULL-TEXT search).

The easiest way with php would be something like:

```
<?php

$ssn = 599151223;

$compare = 533141228;

$ssn = str_split($ssn);
$compare = str_split($compare);

$match_count = 0;

foreach($ssn as $key => $value) {
    if ($compare[$key] == $value)
        $match_count++;
}

if ($match_count == 5) 
    doSomething();

?>
```